# Is Linux disappears to replace Windows?

Tags: windows

I've installed Linux alongside Windows. I have two operating systems (windows and ubuntu).I was assigned one of the drives of Windows to Linux. If I want to change my windows,Do I also need to re-install Linux?

Comment: Please try to [edit] and reword your question, it's unclear what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: please explain. We don't understand what's your issue

Comment: My main question is whether or not I need to reinstall Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by your question. If you've lost your Ubuntu install after installing Windows... [as per help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

1. Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
2. Install and run Boot-Repair
3. Click "Recommended Repair".
4. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.